# No ChromeDrivers found Exception if path is passed using capability - chromedriverExecutableDir

Tags: android, appium

I am able to launch chrome on Android if I use specific chrome driver while starting appium server using below command:

```
appium --chromedriver-executable path/to/chromedriver
```

but when I try to launch the chrome using chromedriverExecutableDir capability as below:

```
File classpath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File app = new File(classpath, "/chromedriver");
cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutableDir", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

its throwing an error saying:

> No Chromedrivers found in path/to/chromedriver

I have also tried using chromedriverExecutable capability

Answer (score 0):

Probably, and my best guess was that you are using a relative path to your chromedriver that's why your appium is reporting that your chromedriver was not found.

Please use Absolute(complete path) when using arguments with appium command via CLI/terminal.

Windows:

```
appium --chromedriver-executable C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe
```

Linux/Mac

```
appium --chromedriver-executable /Users/<username>/Documents/webdrivers/chromedriver
```

Comment: thanks @batuzai04123 for your response but same path when I am using in Terminal its working but not working in capability. Note : I have kept chromedriver.exe on my desktop, hope that does not matter.

Comment: @Ankur can you tell what exact machine are you working on? And what is the exact directory your chromedriver is located, i mean the full path of the file.

Comment: @batuzai04123I am using Mac machine and path for i have kept my chromedriver on Desktop below is the path : /Users/ankur.ankur/Desktop/chromedriver.exe

Comment: Seems wrong @Ankur, you cannot use EXE file on MAC, it only works on Windows machine. Please download the appropriate Unix executable from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/. It looks like you downloaded the win version, please use the MAC version only (named something like chromedriver_mac64.zip).